# csv.DictReader method loads empty cells with empty string

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm running into the issue where python `DictReader` is loading the dictionary, but it is loading the empty csv cell as a empty string. I want it to load it as a `None` value.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: The only fix is for you to write code to bring the data into line with what you want after reading it. What you describe is how the `csv` module is designed to work.

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: are you saying that I would have to modify the dictionary myself?

Comment: Yes. Is that so dreadful?

Comment: nah i'm just asking haha, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is how the `csv` module is designed to work.

The only fix is for you to write code to bring the data into line with what you want after reading it. Like this:

```
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        myfixedrow = {k: (None if v == "" else v) for k,v in row.items()}
```